# JDBC: Apps Script and Google MySQL : Exception: You do not have permission to call Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, jdbc

Code listed below when I attempt to use this function inside my spreadsheet, I get the following error: Google Script Error - Exception: You do not have permission to call Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection

any ideas on how to fix this? The connection is made successfully it seems but gets stuck at create table

```
var connectionName = 'cosmic-tenure-310821:us-central1:propertydata';
var rootPwd = "password";
var user = "root";
var userPwd = 'password';
var db = 'propertydata';

var root = 'root';
var instanceUrl = "jdbc:google:mysql://" + connectionName;
var dbUrl = instanceUrl + "/" + db;

function createTable() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  conn.createStatement().execute('CREATE TABLE myProperties(APN INT, APNObject MEDIUMBLOB)');
}
```

Comment: Does `user` have the necessary permissions to create a table?

Answer (score 0):

try with adding "oauthScopes"

```
"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose"]
```